# VBA for populating only visible cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a row of cells A1:G1 on Sheet2 and I want those values on Sheet1 columns A:G but only on visible rows. I know how to do it through selecting visible cells only and pasting value from Sheet2. But I have many rows and it is incredibly slow. I tried creating an array from cells A1:G1 on Sheet2 and making it a 2D array and then selecting range on Sheet1 and set value in the worksheet but I cannot make the code to work at all. What other ways would you suggest?

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim 2DArr() As Variant

Sheet1.range(cells(1,8),cells(last_row,8). select
activecell.formulaR1C1="=AGGREGATE(3,5,@columnA)"
Arr = Sheet2.Range("A1:G5")
for i=1 to last_row
     if cell(i,8)=1 then
        2DArr(i)=Arr
     End If
Next i

Sheet1.range("A1:G900000")=2DArr
```

Comment: quick note `2Darr()` is an illegal declaration

Answer (score 0):

I admit this is an annoying one: Excel VBA does not have a `Visible` property for its ranges. Instead it has a `Hidden` property which works exactly in the opposite way, as you can see from this simple example:

```
' instead of if RAnge(A1).Visible, you should do:
if NOT(RAnge(A1).Hidden)
```